# Gas mask icon on map

Tags: fallout-4

I've had a glowing/pulsing icon near Sanctuary for some time. It occasionally shows with a chevron pointing upward (so as to indicate "above my altitude"). Does it have something to do what that nuclear fallout storm?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the location of the last power armor you used.